# Rotate Matrix and Delete Characters and Find largest Square

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, matrix, logic

A company manufactures walls which can be directly implanted at the site. The company uses small square bricks of material C and material D which have similar looks but have huge difference in quality. The company manufactures walls of square shapes only to optimize their costs.

A novice employee created a square wall using bricks of material C and D. However, the client had asked the wall to be made of only high-quality material - material C.

To solve this problem, they will place the wall in a special furnace and heat it such that the material D melts and only material C remains. Material C brick will move down due to gravity if a material D brick below it melts. The new empty space created will be filled by new material C square walls. They also want to use biggest possible C square wall while building the final wall. For this they will position the wall in the furnace in an optimal way i.e. rotate by 90-degrees any number of times, if required, such that the biggest space possible for new material C wall is created. No rotations are possible when the furnace starts heating.

Given the structure of the original wall created by the novice employee, you need to find out the size of the new C square wall which can be fitted in the final wall which will be delivered to the client.

Constraints
1 < N < 100

Input
First Line will provide the size of the original wall N.

Next N lines will provide the type of material (C and D) used for each brick by the novice employee.

Output
Size of the biggest possible C square wall which can be fitted in the final wall.

Time Limit
1

Examples
Example 1

Input

4

C D C D

C C D C

D D D D

C D D D

Output

3

Explanation

If the wall is placed with its left side at the bottom, space for a new C wall of size 2x2 can be created. This can be visualized as follows

D C D D

C D D D

D C D D

C C D C

The melted bricks can be visualized as follows

---

- C - -

C C - -

C C - C

Hence, the maximum wall size that can be replaced is 2x2.

If the wall is placed as it is with its original bottom side at the bottom, space for a new C wall of size 3x3 can be created. Post melting, this can be visualized as follows.

---

C - - -

C - - -

C C C C

Hence, the maximum wall size that can be replaced is 3x3 in this approach.

Since no rotations followed by heating is going to a yield a space greater than 3x3, the output is 3.

Example 2

Input

7

C D D C D D D

C D D C D D D

D D D D D D C

D C D C D D D

D D D C D C D

C D D C D C C

C D C D C C C

Output

5

Explanation

If the wall is placed with its left side at the bottom, a space for new C wall of size 5x5 can be created. This can be visualized as follows

D D C D D C C

D D D D C C C

D D D D D D C

C C D C C C D

D D D D D D C

D D D C D D D

C C D D D C C

When this orientation of the wall is heated, a space for new C wall of size 5x5 is created after the D bricks melt

---

---

_ _ _ _ _ _C

_ _ _ _ _ C C

_ _ _ _ _ C C

C C _ C C C C

C C C C C C C

Whereas, if the rotation was not done, the wall formed after the D bricks melt will be as follows

---

---

_ _ _ C _ _ _

C _ _ C _ _ _

C _ _ C _ _ C

C _ _ C _ C C

C C C C C C C

When this orientation of the wall is heated, a space for new C wall of size 3x3 only is created after the D bricks melt

Hence rotation is important and correct answer is 5x5

Since no rotations followed by heating is going to a yield a space greater than 5x5, the output is 5.

```
// matrix rotation by 90 degrees
void rotate90Clockwise(int a[N][N]) 
{ 
  
    // Traverse each cycle 
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) { 
        for (int j = i; j < N - i - 1; j++) { 
  
            // Swap elements of each cycle 
            // in clockwise direction 
            int temp = a[i][j]; 
            a[i][j] = a[N - 1 - j][i]; 
            a[N - 1 - j][i] = a[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j]; 
            a[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j] = a[j][N - 1 - i]; 
            a[j][N - 1 - i] = temp; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you want us to write some code for you? What have **you** tried?

Comment: @Evg, I wrote the code for rotation but I am confused how to delete 'D" and get maximum size subarray after that ... I know the logic but code implementation problems is frustratiing me

Comment: Then I suggest you ask a more specific question about the implementation problem you have and show some code you have so far. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would start by separating the logic into different classes and methods e.g. have one that rotates the walls sends it for melting to a furnace class which melts and applies gravity. Then maybe a third class that gives you the largest square to fit. Need to iterate over various rotations of the wall and remember the largest possible square.

Comment: A simple way to implement melting is to iterate over columns, replace `D` with `0` and use `std::sort` to sort by ascending order. Do this for each column.

Comment: @erfan, thanks for your valuable suggestions. I also had the same logic but I am facing problems on how to code that. Any code help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @erfan, I have the code to rotate matrix.

Comment: Never underestimate the importance of showing your work

Comment: @user4581301, I don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what data structure you get the wall in, but assuming it is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> wall;
```

To be able to perform melting using `std::sort`, it is best to have columns in the outer vector and rows in the inner vectors.

```
// melting bricks
for (int col = 0; col < wall.size(); ++col) //column of bricks
{
    for (int row = 0; row < wall[0].size(); ++row) //row of bricks
    {
        if (wall[col][row] == 'D') wall[col][row] = 0;
    }
}

// applying gravity i.e. sorting
for (int col = 0; col < wall.size(); ++col) //column of bricks
{
    std::sort(wall[column].begin(), wall[column].end());
}
```

I haven't tested this so you may need to debug.

To find the largest square to fit in, one way is to rotate the wall and melt for each rotation, then searching for largest square, perhaps by using a while loop.

Also, it's important to organize your code into classes e.g. Wall, Furnace, etc.

Comment: Code for rotation updated in your code.

Comment: just last thing would you please combine all the code to a working one

Comment: I gave code for rotation in the question itself.

Comment: Please adopt this as per the structure you are using for the wall. I used `std::vector` not knowing it was actually an array. But the basic idea to work this out is the same. @SarahKaiser

Comment: Thanks a lot @erfan, you helped a lot. Just combining the codes... Will help me even further.

Comment: did you made a complete working code. Please tell if you made....